# Composer / Satis - turn off verify peer?

Tags: php, composer-php, satis

I am trying to set up Satis to talk to a private Subversion repository I have installed on my localhost. Because the certificate is self signed, satis is not connecting (I get the message that it could not validate the certificate). Company rules require HTTPS because of the user authentication information, so I can't just switch the repo to HTTP. How do I disable verify peer in Satis?

This is my config for the repo in satis.json:

```
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://svn.company.com:8443/svn/project/",
    "options": {
        "ssl": {
            "verify_peer": false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no verify peer option in `composer` or `satis`.  There is configuration for changing the `cafile` or `capath`.

Answer (score -1):

No one should be disabling peer verification or enabling insecure http.

You should get a cert - and thats it.

Tell your boss that you need another one... or use a "Let's encrypt" client to setup the cert. Its a matter of 5 minutes.